# All the moderators have been kidnapped!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

I'm a bit worried. I just got an email from mods@puzzling.stackexchange.com. It looked like this:

> Dear Puzzling Users:
>
> Hello - you don't know me, but I have been watching your site for months. I have looked at new puzzles, monitored the election, read new answers, read chat transcripts, and generally stalked your precious site. And I have finally decided to test your mad puzzling skills out for... a purpose. I have kidnapped your moderators. Yes, that was blunt - I have to be sure that I have your attention, for your mods' sakes. I have allowed them each to include a screenshot in this email, with a puzzle to their current locations.
>
> Here is the mod known as 'Rubi*o*'s scr*e*en*s*ho*t* - he appe*a*rs to *g*reatly like his profile:
>
> [image: Qvq lbh ybbx ng gur frpgvba nobir?]
>
> Next we lo*o*k at what the perso*n* going by 'Gentle*P*urpleRain placed, hoping you to e*xt*ract som*e* information. It appears to *b*e t*h*e site's usu*a*lly empty review *q*ueues:
>
> [image: mold mold mold mold mold mold mold mold mold mold mold mold mold]
>
> Next we have the person with the alias Gareth McCaughan's screenshot choice. He has included a picture of the main chat for the Puzzling Stack Exchange site. The Sphinx's Lair - ah, I know the place well, from my stalking of it. Here is his slightly blurred out screenshot:
>
> [image: lat]
>
> And now, the admirable Deusovi. Deusovi has chosen a screenshot of the front page. I am afraid that he has hidden his location *too* well - you may find this *too* difficult. Oh well - his loss.
>
> [image: <s><i><b> ebgguvegrra]
>
> Stellar. The pictures are included. Every picture has that mods location. GentlePurpleRain has even had a hint for his put in Rubio's puzzle.
>
> After you have solved them, travel to the locations and contact me again. Not before.
>
> Once again, goodbye, my Puzzling friends!
>
> --Gloatingly,
>   Ralph Albert Phil Hershy Young
>
> <sub>That's a pseudonym, just in case you wanted to track me...</sub>

I think it might be a hoax, but Rubio hasn't show up for Spyfall, so I'm getting a bit worried. Where could they be?

Comment: Rubio's medals are bit different. Probably special medals for moderators :p

Comment: Good thing I didn't make it in the election. pfew.

Comment: I say we don't find them and start posting a bunch of low quality questions.

Comment: I agree with Forklift. No one solve it. Let em stay kidnapped! /s

Comment: @Forklift. Won't work. The community can delete the low quality questions also. But you can start preparing your resume for the new election that is coming.

Comment: It was Rubio. Definitely

Comment: 112119111 view in screenshot of Rubio's profile. What does that mean? It must be some sort of hint.

Comment: otgonpxtebhaqnref -  collection of all the letters in italics

Comment: @AshutoshDave I can get `Xenophobe` out of these letters. :)

Comment: @AshutoshDave ROT13 to brfgntbackground

Comment: :3 Anyone else catch the hidden tag in the outro?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rubio is in

> **Anchorage, Alaska**. His rep accounts on different sites can be concatenated and split to get "1 14 003 8 15 18 1 6", which is ANCHORAF [sic] in A1Z26. His absurdly high number of views can be combined and split similarly to get "1 12 1 19 11 1", or ALASKA.

GentlePurpleRain is in

> **London**. The text above their screenshot has italicized letters; combining and rot13ing them gives the phrase "background". Hidden in the lower left corner (colored to blend in with the background) is LONDON.

Gareth is in

> **Shanghai**. We can see in the chat sidebar that someone named "**N**ero" sent the message "31.2304". We can also see lots of Es in Gareth's search bar. Taking the lengths of those **E**s gives "121.4737".
>
>  Those give a latitude and longitude - 31.2304 N, 121.4737 E. This is the center of Shanghai.

I am in

> -- er, *on*, Easter Island. There are many letters bolded, italicized, and underlined. Taking those, then rot13ing them gives EASTERISLAND.

Comment: ...Now for the bonus, count the words ;)

Comment: When you say underlined do you mean struck-through?